# .pro for Qt/Ros?

Tags: ros, qt4

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I know that you can use CMake with Qt, and I do, but what is the reason for not using .pro files? As far as I understand, the reason is rosmake does not have rosmake files, just CMake files. Is this a correct assessment? I am only asking for curiosity...

thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39572/.pro-for-qt/ros?/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosmake is just a wrapper around make plus dependency management. All it does is expanding the dependency tree and calling make inside ros packages in the right order.

QMake is a very specialized tool for Qt development while most packages don't use Qt at all. CMake on the other hand provides great flexibility through macros, custom targets, etc.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
Actually, you can use qmake in the same way independent of Qt. Nevertheless, cmake is the easier tool to use for this (imo).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-24**:
I know that it doesn't depend on it. But just out of curiosity, do you know if it provides ways to integrate external tools such as rospack and generic tests for library, e.g. using pkg-config. I always had the feeling that it is pretty restricted.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
pkgconfig is supported and you can do things like call a system command (rospack find) and use its output, custom build targets. cmake seems to be nicer to me. I remember setting up custom flex/bison targets was not pretty (but possible).